# Laravel - Get current .env() Value

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a Laravel project. I often change the database connection between Mysql and Sqlite during development. In a php artisan Laravel command I have an import routine. Because I don't want to write the data into the wrong database, I want to set an if condition before the import. But unfortunately it doesn't work quite as I imagined.

```php
if ( env('DB_CONNECTION', null ) === 'sqlite') {
   // Import to sqlite
} else if (env('DB_CONNECTION') === 'mysql') {
  // Import to mysql
} else {
  // no database in env DB_CONNECTION
}
```

In my `.env` file currrently the `DB_CONNECTION` is set on `sqlite`. But `env('DB_CONNECTION', null)` returns null.

What do I have to do to find out the current connection? Maybe using env() is not the right choice at this point?

Comment: just curious, where is your code above sitting?

Comment: .env is the correct location, but you have to add the .env var in your config and read it with `config()` . reading directly from `env()`will not work in many cases

Comment: @kapitan Thank for your  curios and question. the file with this condition is located under `app/Console/Commands/myImportCommand.php`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `if(env('DB_CONNECTION') == 'sqlite')` only on the first line? also, i am assuming that you're doing `php artisan config:cache` everytime you're changing something at the `.env` file right?

Comment: @kapitan i don't think so because i can have three statuses: 1. sqlite, 2.mysql, 3. null. with only one if {} else i would equate null with a valid value.

Comment: can't you make a separate `else if` statement for the null value? `else if(!env('DB_CONNECTION'))`

Comment: @kapitan Of course, this is also possible, but what would be the advantage of the current if-conditioning routine? env('DB_CONNECTION', null) return null

Comment: Ohh no! The solution was `php artisan config:clear` I'm such a fool! Sorry to waste your time @kapitan and Gert B.

Comment: You should have a `config/database.php`. Mine has this default for `DB_CONNECTION`: `env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')`. As stated above you might need to use [`config()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values). Can you find the value in `$_ENV` (just for debugging)? *Edit: Oh seems resolved, sorry.*

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thank you for your comment! I have found the solution. My code works fine the way it is! But my mistake was that I didn't clear my config cache after I reset the variable. Merci for your time!!!!

Comment: @MaikLowrey - i already said that on my 2nd comment. thank you.

Comment: @kapitan Im sorry! I accidentally overlooked that. I will reciprocate.

Comment: no problem. I'm happy that you found the solution. (smile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those who will have the same problem in the future. **Always**! But really **always**, after you have modified the .env variable, you should execute the following "cleaning" commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

If you still don't get a value, ask SO.

Comment: you only need to do `config:cache` because it would automatically make a `clear` command before it would cache the config files.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not use `env()` function anywhere except config files. Instead, use `config('database.default')`, because when configuration is cached, the env is empty for security reasons.
2. You may create multiple database connections in `config/database.php` and switch between them manually using facade: `DB::connection('sqlite')`, or `DB::connection('mysql')` and avoid this ugly `if - else if` tree.

Comment: Since it's local only, you could use the if (env('APP_ENV') == 'local'){DB::connection('sqlite'); }  Strange why you wouldn't run the same env in dev as production though.

Comment: In production you usually run `artisan optimize`, which caches routes, configs in files with php arrays. After this your $_ENV is not loaded. Reference - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/calling-env-function-in-production-mode-from-config-file. You will not change your code for production every time. Using config works everywhere.

Comment: Yup caching is good in prod.  I meant running the same server/hosting environment.  Like in my case I run a vm of RedHat with a full MySql server locally for dev that matches production.  I've found too many times if you aren't developing on the same environments there could be quirks in how code runs.  In one of my projects I do have 3 database connections 1 main in env file and 2 fully dynamic that are independent of the main Laravel database connection.

Comment: There are several reasons, like for testing - sqlite is much more "mobile" as it allows keeping the whole database in RAM with 0 configuration and in most cases will probably work the same as mysql. But this is definitely not the author's case and other topic to talk.